# Windows 10 Setup thinks it's booted from installation media

Tags: windows-10, installation, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade, setup

This has been happening for all Windows 10 Setup builds. Windows Setup will not let me upgrade or downgrade my build (currently 11082) without losing my apps. I always get this message right after I click "**Upgrade**":

> The computer started using the Windows installation media. Remove the installation media and restart your computer so that Windows starts normally. Then, insert the installation media and restart the upgrade. (Do not select "Custom (advanced)" to perform an upgrade. "Custom (advanced)" installs a new copy of Windows and deletes your programs and settings.)

I have tried opening setup from flash drives, tried in C:\, you name it I tried it, but every time I open setup (I even tried the setup.exe found in the sources folder), it refuses to upgrade due to it thinking "`the computer started using the Windows installation media`".

Note: The same installation files from the same flash drive worked to upgrade my laptop's Windows 10 build (which was also at build 11082), so I know the files in the installation folder are legit.

Here are some screenshots:

1. I get this when I open setup.exe only on my PC:

   [image: image 1]
2. It then asks me for a key:

   [image: image 2]
3. Then after agreeing to the Windows license policy and clicking on "**Upgrade**", I get the error which I wrote above.

   [image: image 3]

I have fixed the partitioning to match the Microsoft recommended specification, and I have even tried booting the installation from another PC, but to no avail.

Here is my setupact.log: http://pastebin.com/2WMe30Kn

SetupErr.log: http://pastebin.com/bZAHMvJg

Another question that is related to the same installation: https://superuser.com/questions/1080846/windows-installation-has-no-idea-of-itself

Any thoughts before I entirely give up upgrading once and for all?

Comment: Do you happen to have any other drives on the machine, especially ones with a bootable OS?

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you tried using the Windows 10 installation tool available in a link at [Get Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) on the PC you are hoping to upgrade.

Comment: I used an iso and placed the image on my flash drive (bootable and all). The Windows 10 installation tool does not allow one to upgrade to a preview build unfortunately.

Comment: Verify the system disk with chksk and ensure it has enough free space. Update all your drivers and the BIOS, before running setup.exe from USB.

Comment: I actually performed all of those, I even copied the setup files to the SSD itself and running from within it, but it still thought I booted from installation media.

Comment: Do you have **any** removable media plugged in? i.e. a thumb drive

Comment: Tried with and without, but refuses still.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same weird behavior when trying a Windows 10 upgrade. Ultimately, my decision was to install from scratch. Definitely the right call. My main issue was that I didn't have a partition structure that Windows liked. STRONGLY recommend a fresh install on a physical drive (SSD of course) with only the Windows partitions: System, MSR, Windows, and Recovery.  Yes, 4 partitions on Drive 0. I was able to use the guidance from MSDN about [UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510(v=vs.85).aspx).

I didn't have to use Windows PE as specified in the article because you can run the CreatePartitions batch from any Windows machine. Using the GPT version (not the MBR version) is highly advisable for 2TB and high drives (I had a 256G SSD, several 3TB drives, and a 5TB drive). Just save this to a CMD file and CHANGE THE DRIVE NUMBER to your physical drive. Run DISKPART LIST DISK to verify the disk number.

```
rem    Create four partitions for a UEFI/GPT-based Windows PC.
rem    Adjust the partition sizes to fill the drive as necessary.

select disk <NUMBER>
clean
convert gpt

rem == 1. System partition =========================
create partition efi size=100
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter="S"

rem == 2. Microsoft Reserved (MSR) partition =======
create partition msr size=16

rem == 3. Windows partition ========================
rem ==    a. Create the Windows partition ==========
create partition primary 
rem ==    b. Create space for the recovery tools ===
shrink minimum=500
rem ==    c. Prepare the Windows partition ========= 
format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows"
assign letter="W"

rem === 4. Recovery tools partition ================
create partition primary
format quick fs=ntfs label="Recovery tools"
assign letter="R"
set id="de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac"
gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001
list volume
exit
```

The first time I did it, I ran all of the commands manually from CMD. Much easier to see what's going on that way. Also, if you have Windows "Disk Management" (run diskmgmt.msc) running, you'll see the results in near real time.

Hope this helps.  It saved me, and my Windows install has never been happier.

**Pro tip:** don't enter your serial number when installing... make sure you have a good install and just enter it later. Click "I don't have a product key" instead.

Comment: hmm, I had deleted the recovery partitions a long while ago, I'll try regenerating them and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: I created the necessary partitions and modified them in order to be precisely conformant to the Microsoft specifications, yet the issue persists :( ...

Comment: Then you've stumped me. I guess I would start trying to swap out drives, try on another computer, etc. Even since answering this, I'll bet I've done this a dozen more times with no dead ends. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, had to format and reinstall. Oh well, good riddance I guess...

Comment: Hey @MathuSumMut Turns out there is another reason that this can fail even is everything above seems to work. **Some PCs just won't install from USB.** I tried an insane number of permutations to try an install just now. Nothing worked. That is, until I pulled out all the USB drive and tried a CD/DVD install. Worked first try.

Comment: Oh wow, that's sad actually...at least you figured it out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just select advanced. Then select the partition on which you want the  installation to take place.

If you want to keep your files, do not format or delete the partition on which  you are installing.